# Sending Data to Website From iPhone

Tags: iphone, save, numeric

I'm creating an iPhone Game where I want the user to get a **unique numeric code** when they first launch the app, that way when a friend of that user opens it, he/she can input that code and **both users can get rewarded**. I haven't encountered any issues regarding that, however what I want to do is make it to where the **app registers the code given to every user** and **saves it to a website** of some sort. That way when the other user enters the code, it will **load the data from that website** and check if it's registered. **How would I manage to save the data onto a website?** and also What free website could I use for this without having a character limit on the body page?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is correct, in that you need to save your data somewhere online, but you don't really "save data onto a website" in the way that you're describing. "Free Website" services usually serve a different purpose entirely - that of serving up public html pages. Sure, they can take the form of a CMS (like wordpress.com or tumblr accounts), but using that as an interface for storing your application's data is not something they're typically designed to do.

For something like this, where you have a public iPhone app that requires secure access to custom strings, you really want to have control over your own web server (different than a  domain name, btw), and interface with a database on that server. This will come at a cost, and will involve more code than you're likely to find someone to write for you on here. Sorry to say it, but hey if someone wants to prove me wrong I'd love to see it.

Because all you need to store & retrieve are random strings (basically referral codes... if I'm understanding correctly), your database needs are pretty simple. If you're not familiar with things like PHP / MySQL, and you don't want to learn, it might be worth reaching out to some server-side developers for help. Unless there's more to it than you describe, you can probably find someone to help you for relatively cheap.

Good luck - and I'm sorry there isn't a simpler answer for ya.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Just create an [`NSMutableURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and call its `-setHTTPMethod:` method with “POST” as the HTTP method. Then, set its body and header fields appropriately, and you can use `NSURLConnection` to send the data.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, I get the concept of what you're saying though. Could you provide me with a sample code of some sort? and also how could I manage to modify the data on the website? I don't own any domains or anything, are there any websites you know of that could provide me with something useful?

Comment: It’s hard to write generic sample code without knowing what you’re doing. For hosting the service you could check out [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).